# Can I have ResearchGate organize peer review of my paper?

Tags: peer-review, open-access, online-publication, social-media

I've uploaded an article to ResearchGate, and ResearchGate asks me whether it has been peer reviewed. It hasn't, and I'm wondering whether ResearchGate can get it peer reviewed for me.

Is this possible and if yes how would I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by organizing the peer review on researchgate? You want to invite researcher and comment on your article or something else?

Comment: When you say _publish_, do you mean publish on ResearchGate, or publish in a journal (which ResearchGate isn't)? When you say _uploading website_, do you mean that of ResearchGate, or that of a journal?

Comment: No indeed I mean upload on Research Gate - Nonetheless Research Gate is no journal, by peer reviewing the quality of the publication would be increased

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I understand your question now. You've uploaded your article to ResearchGate, and ResearchGate asks you whether it has been peer reviewed. It hasn't, and now you're wondering whether ResearchGate can get it peer reviewed for you.

The answer is: it can't. It just wants to mark articles shared on RG that have been peer reviewed elsewhere as such, but it won't have it reviewed for you. To get it reviewed, you would have to submit it to an actual journal.

Answer (score 7):

Research gate is not a journal or other form of publication outlet. It's a sort of researcher's facebook with an option to upload papers or preprints of papers that were published elsewhere. These are not peer-reviewed (again) by research gate.

Comment: Sure, but nonetheless many people just load up articles on research gate without "publishing" it elsewhere. This might be the reason why they ask for a peer-review

Comment: @2Obe Such people perhaps should consider an epijournal, if a suitable one exists. However, that is still a form of getting the article published.

Comment: @2Obe Is that actually common?! Because as far as I know RG was never intended for that, and it’s a patently bad idea.

Comment: I think if there is not the intention that people upload articles (only) on RG (indipendent if the article has been published or not), the question if the paper has been peer-reviewed is obsolete since if users would only load up published articles they are all (normally) reviewed

Comment: @2Obe working papers, and in some disciplines, conference papers aren't. There are also journals without peer review. In law, these are the majority.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the answer is no.

Research gate is a site for displaying your work so people can find it. It is not part of the publishing process itself.

Peer-review is what happens after you submit the paper to a journal, before they accept it. I find it strange that the publisher would ask if the paper has been peer-reviewed. Possibly the intended question is whether it has previously been submitted to (and rejected by) another journal, so they can ask to see previous reviews before using up more community time on further ones.

Edit: I can't make up my mind whether the website you are uploading to is Research Gate itself or another journal website. If you mean Research Gate, then the 'is it peer reviewed?' question means 'Has it been accepted for publication?'